# Does entrywise asymptotic similarity of functions translate to the asymptotic similarity of the corresponding determinants with these as entries?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, analysis

Let $A(x) = [a_{ij}(x)], B(x)=[b_{ij}(x)]$ be two $n \times n$ matrices so that $a_{ij}(x) \sim  b_{ij}(x), i.e. \frac{a_{ij}(x)}{b_{ij}(x)}\to 1, x \to 0.$

**Note:** By "asymptotic similarity", I meant "$\sim.$"

I was wondering whether in general it is true that:

$$det(A(x)) \sim det (B(x)), i.e. \frac{det(A(x)}{det(B(x))} \to 1, x \to 0?$$

It intuitively seems yes at least for many cases, but finer points need to be checked.

And if it's not true in general, is there a sufficient condition for the above to be guaranteed?

**Addendum:** I'm more interested in the case where each $a_{ij}(x), b_{ij}(x)\to 0,$ so both $det(A(x)), det(B(x)) \to 0$ as well. **More particularly, in a practical example**, I'm considering the $n \times n$ matrix where all the entries are of the form $a_{ij}(x) \sim b_{ij} x^k, k > 0,  b_{ij}\ne 0, x \to 0, k$ being the same for each entry: so they have exactly the same decay rate for each $i,j.$. I was wondering whether I could write: $det(A(x)) \sim (x^k)^n det B,$ A(x), B being the matrices from $a_{ij}(x), B$ respectively.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a application of the limit laws for functions.

Comment: @garondal Thanks! So the answer is yes or no? :)

Comment: No, let me write it out as answer.

Comment: @garondal Thank you - if you could point to a sufficient condition where the answer will be yes, that'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The answer is no as you can have cancellations that destroy everything. See my comment below the current answer. It seems difficult to have interesting sufficient conditions.

Comment: If you have some particular example in mind, please let us know. It seems quite hard to find general conditions that make this true. If I had to bet, I'd say to a family of generic perturbations of a singular matrix does not satisfy that the conclusion you'd like.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Many thanks for your comments and your answer - upvoted! In a practical example I'm considering the $n \times n$ matrix where all the entries are of the form $a_{ij}(x) \sim b_{ij} x^k, k > 0,  b_{ij}\ne 0, x \to 0, k$ being the same for each entry: so they have exactly the same decay rate for each $i,j.$. I was wondering whether I could write: $det(A(x)) \sim (x^k)^n det B,$ A(x), B being the matrices from $a_{ij}(x), B$ respectively.

Comment: @LearningMath Yes, you can just pull the factors of $x$ out. However, as you can see in my example even in that setting we cannot ensure that the determinants have the same asymptotic (due to cancellation). In fact, in my example I can pick all the coefficients the same, except for the top left entry.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thanks - so just to make sure, the answer to the specific question I wrote right above is yes, i.e. in this very specific case, $det(A(x))\sim (x^k)^n det B?$ Just checking. I assumed this initially, but then I think I wrongly generalized it too much.

Comment: @LearningMath No, this is still not true. Take my example below with $k=1$. In fact, this type of scaling does not change the question at all as the determinant is multilinear, thus we can just pull out a factor of $\vert x \vert^{kn}$ and reduce it to the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not true and the main reason is that we can have cancellations. Consider the example
$$ A(x)=\begin{pmatrix} x + x^2 & x \\ x & x \end{pmatrix}, B(x) = \begin{pmatrix} x + x^3 & x \\ x & x \end{pmatrix}. $$
Then all the entries go to zero and all have the same asymptotic for $x\rightarrow 0$. However, we have
$$ \det(A(x)) = x^3, \det(B(x)) = x^4 $$
so the corresponding determinants do not have the same asymptotics.

One might believe that this is because all the entries have the same asymptotics and so cancellation messes things up. Thus, one might be tempted to impose that one of the entries is bigger than the others to prevent such a nightmare from happening. However, because we also multiply coefficients that is also not good enough as the following example shows

$$ \tilde{A}(x)= \begin{pmatrix} \vert x \vert^{3/2} + \vert x \vert^{5/2} & x \\ x & \vert x \vert^{1/2} \end{pmatrix}, \tilde{B}(x) = \begin{pmatrix} \vert x \vert^{5/2} + \vert x \vert^{5/2} & x \\ x & \vert x \vert^{1/2} \end{pmatrix}. $$

I cannot think of a reasonable condition that makes that statement true.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{x}&0\\0&x+1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}\frac{1}{x}&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}$. There you have $\frac{a_{ij}(x)}{b_{ij}(x)} \rightarrow 1$.

We have det$(A)=1+\frac{1}{x}$ and det$(B)=1$ for every $x$.

The problem is that you do not prevent the case $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{1}{x} \rightarrow \infty$.

It would be sufficient if you would say that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} a_{ij}=M_{ij}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} b_{ij}(x)$ where $M_{ij}$ is a real number. Since the determinant is the product and sum of convergent functions you have (using the [limit laws](https://www.utrgv.edu/cstem/utrgv-calculus/limits/limit-laws/index.htm)) that $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\text{det}(A(x)) = \lim_{x \rightarrow 0}\text{det}(B(x))$.

Comment: Your last paragraph does not look correct to me. For example $$ \begin{pmatrix} 1+x^2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 1+x & 1 \\ 1 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$ Cancellations are a big enemy too.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: Thanks for the hint! I will adopt my answer. You will "only" have that $\lim det(A)= \lim det(B)$.

Comment: @garondal Thanks for your answer but if the final conclusion is only that the limit of the determinants are equal, then it doesn't answer my question - so when can we say that the ratio of the determinants goes to one, i.e. $det(A(x)/det(B(x)\to 1, x\to 0?$ When $det(B) \to l \ne 0?$

I'm going to edit my question when each $a_{ij}(x), b_{ij}(x) \to 0, x\to 0.$

Comment: Sorry for the missunderstanding. Yes, that should be enough.

Comment: @garondal No, your example shows that $\det(B) \rightarrow l \neq 0$ is not enough. And the counterexample that I gave above still stands even when we multiply every entry with $x$ to make the entries go to zero.